# Issues upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, 23.04

Trying to upgrade from 22.04 to 23.04.  As it prepares to update, and is in the setting new software channels, it hangs on 210 of 216, then errors out with the following error:

> A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of
> network problem, please check your network connection and retry.
>
> W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is
> therefore disabled by default., W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for
> repository creation and user configuration details., E:The repository
> 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-updates Release' does not
> have a Release file.

I have network connection and can browse without issue, however, if I go to that URL, I get a 404. I have been trying for the last several days, at different parts of the day with no luck.  Anyone else in the same boat?  Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Look at your output again: `hirsute-updates`. What does the release name "hirsute (hippo)" suggest to you?